# Order of HTML element bindings in Svelte

Tags: binding, svelte

New to Svelte here and playing with the reactivity concept. This first example works, the file input field correctly shows the selected file.

```js
<script>
  let files = []
</script>

<input type='file' bind:files />
```

This second example (only swapped the input attributes) does not. As can be easily tested in the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.12.1).

```js
<script>
  let files = []
</script>

<input bind:files type='file' />
```

It complains with "Value being assigned to HTMLInputElement.files does not implement interface FileList." and I don't understand why... do the bindings always have to go last in Svelte?

Comment: Looks like you've found a bug! I've raised an issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3828. Btw, to share a REPL link you need to log in to the REPL (with your GitHub account) and hit the 'save' icon — the link above is to the 'hello world' REPL

Comment: @RichHarris Cool... I guess. ;) I noticed you can save REPL links, just trying to avoid "yet another account". Thanks for monitoring SO, I will open an issue on Github next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RichHarris explains above... this is a bug in Svelte. For now simply add the bindings to the end of the input element until it has been fixed.

See the [Github issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3828) for more info.

UPDATE: This has been fixed in November 2019 (see [pull request #3849](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/3849)).